# Should I use ObservableObject in Managers

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Im learning about `SwiftUI` for macOS development, and Im wondering what would be the right approach when creating Managers, services etc. These are objects not related to the UI - strictly business logic things, not even `ViewModels`. Should I not use things like `ObservableObject`, `Published`, `AppStorage`, etc. in this kind of classes? On one hand it seems to be beneficial to add this, so that I can later easily use them with `ViewModels`, and bind directly to some properties. On the other hand it seems wrong - like these property wrappers are strictly `SwiftUI` related. So should I resign from these things in managers, services and other business logic objects?

Comment: If the manager is not related to the UI, conforming to `ObservableObject` is pointless. It's good practice anyway to separate managers from ViewModels.

Comment: Well they are not directly related to Views but still somehow impact them. Maybe let's consider an example - A Library object (manager) that stores and manages the list of files of certain type. And then let's say we have a LibraryView and LibraryViewModel which display the content of library. In this situation would you consider making Library, being manager to conform to ObservableObject or use something different for binding? I know I would still need to bridge Published objects from Library to LibraryViewModel, but this can also be done quite easily.

Comment: Well, this depends on the definition – and distinction – of *Manager* and *View Model*. My definition is: A manager is something like a Core Location manager which notifies the view model about the changes, or the class containing the Core Data stack or a download manager which is called on demand – in terms of Swift Concurrency an *actor*. A view model manages those data and drives the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `ObservableObject` and `Published` are defined in Combine, so they are fine to use outside of the UI layer of your app. On the contrary, `@AppStorage` is defined in SwiftUI, so you should only use it in `View`s.

However, the fact that something is defined in Combine doesn't necessarily mean that it provides meaningful value to use when not binding to your UI.

`ObservableObject`'s main use case is storing objects as `@ObservedObject` on a `View` and getting automatic view updates. Even though you could consume the `objectWillChange` `Publisher` that `ObservableObject` provides from outside a view, there's not much use for it, so in general, I wouldn't advice on making objects conform to `ObservableObject` unless they are directly updating your SwiftUI views.

`@Published` on the other hand provides significant value even outside your ViewModel-View interaction. Observing changes to mutable state is quite useful even in a pure business logic layer, such as exposing the current location of the user in a location manager class and observing it from a view model. Marking this property `@Published` makes it much easier to observe.

The separation of what objects a View should directly access is a subjective topic, so I won't go into that in much detail, but if you want to keep your View independent of your business logic objects other than the ViewModel, you should store managers, services, etc on your ViewModel and proxy any properties that need to update the UI through the ViewModel. For this to work, you don't need to make your managers/services conform to `ObservableObject`, however, storing mutable state as `@Published` can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableObject` allows you to store state in an object that is independent from any views. When you conform your class to `ObservableObject` then views can *observe it* (or *listen*). To *broadcast* (*publish*) values of your variables to the views, just mark them with property wrapper `@Published`. Obviously, you know that.
I consider this pattern as strictly dedicated to Object->Views communication.